# How to send e-mail in users selected languages

Tags: 7, emails

- I have created two users and my site supported two languages(English,Spanish).
- In every 5 hours CRON will be run,I have wrote a custom module and every CRON run users are getting Emails thats fine.
- But here is the problem is Emails are not sended to users prefered languages,it takes admin default language and sended to users.

I have installled multilingual module also.

I want Emails should be in users prefered languages only.

**Code:-**

```
function sendmail($from, $to, $firstname, $message, $user,$language) {
  $module = "my_mail_example";
  $key = "mail_example";
  $language = user_preferred_language();
  $send = TRUE;
  $params = array(
    'body' => $message,
    'subject' => 'Hello from Bright Ideas'
  );
  $result = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);  
  $current_messages = $user -> field_reminder_messages_received[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  $updated_messages = $current_messages.'\r\n'.$logmessage;  
  $edit = array(
      'field_reminder_messages_received' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array('value' => $updated_messages, ), ), ),
    );
  user_save($user, $edit);  
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question related to "multilingual module", by including the exact name and URL of the module(s) you are referring to. Is it 'i18n'? If so consider using that tag also.

Comment: You can wrap your message and subject like `$message = t($message); $subject = t($subject);` and then make a translation by visiting `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`

Answer (score 2):

Cron runs as the anonymous user, so any emails sent by cron will use the site's default language.

Your code snippet has the following:

```
 $language = user_preferred_language();
```

This is wrong.  It will get the preferred language of the anonymous user, not the user you're sending the mail to.

Instead: figure out the recipient's preferred language:

```
$userobj = user_load($user);
$language = user_preferred_language($userobj);
```

Now, you can send mail with the correct language:

```
$result = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params, $from, $send);
```

Comment: i didn.t get  your answer,can you please elaborate bit more.

Comment: What is it you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the receiver email in the $to variable, so...

```
//here you load the user that has the $to email
$receiver = user_load_by_mail($to);



//here you have the preferred language of that user
$langcode = $receiver->getPreferredLangcode();
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Note that the question is regarding D7 and this answer would be for D8

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that.